# Is there a way to store in same database row divided in two forms?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that gets some information, then redirects to html static pages, and comes back to another form to store the contact information (phone). I wonder if somehow i can save or set the same id of data inserted before, so I can insert the phone in the right row. I uploaded the project so you can have a better understanding:
[link to website](https://testedeferias.000webhostapp.com/)

Here's the code of first form data insert:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$pdo = new PDO(''); //removed this line for security
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (isset($_POST['nome']))
{
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dados VALUES(null,?,?,?,?)");

    $sql->execute(array(
        $_POST['nome'],
        $_POST['profissao'],
        $_POST['idade'],
        $_POST['telefone']
    ));    
}

echo "<br/>";

if (isset($_POST['r1']))
{
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO respostasVALUES(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $sql->execute(array(
        $_POST['r1'],
        $_POST['r2'],
        $_POST['r3'],
        $_POST['r4'],
        $_POST['r5'],
        $_POST['r6'],
        $_POST['p1'],
        $_POST['p2'],
        $_POST['hotel']
    ));
}
?>
```

And here's the second form insert:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$pdo = new PDO(""); //removed for security
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (isset($_POST["telefone"])) 
{
    $sql = $pdo->prepare(
        "UPDATE dados SET telefone=? WHERE id = 'LAST_INSERT_ID()'"
    );
    $sql->execute([$_POST["telefone"]]);
}
?>
```

I can't get that to work, some help would be appreciated. I'm also new into programming, so please, be comprehensive.

Comment: just include the ID of the row you're editing in the form as a hidden field `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='10' />` - it will submit with your phone field and you can grab it there: `"UPDATE dados SET telefone=? WHERE id = ?"` ... `array($_POST['telefone'], $_POST['id'])`

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` shouldn't be in quotes.

Comment: with or without quotes it doesn't work

Comment: last_INSERT_ID works only on the same se4ssion, so make a multi query and both qury in on go

Comment: Not same session, but same database connection. And since you are making a new one in your second script, this won't work. You need to get the ID after you make the query in the first script, and then pass it on to the second one. For example via a hidden form field (could get manipulated by the user), or by putting it into a session variable.